# Extract the error message from the shell script using Python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I have a simple Python script which will execute a shell script using `subprocess` mdoule in Python.

Below is my Python shell script which is calling `testing.sh` shell script and it works fine.

```
import os
import json
import subprocess

jsonData = '{"pp": [0,3,5,7,9], "sp": [1,2,4,6,8]}'
jj = json.loads(jsonData)

print jj['pp']
print jj['sp']

os.putenv( 'jj1',  'Hello World 1')
os.putenv( 'jj2',  'Hello World 2')
os.putenv( 'jj3', ' '.join( str(v) for v in jj['pp']  ) )
os.putenv( 'jj4', ' '.join( str(v) for v in jj['sp']  ) )

print "start"
proc = subprocess.Popen('testing.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if stderr:
   print "Shell script gave some error"
else:
   print "end" # Shell script ran fine.
```

And below is my `testing.sh` shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

for el1 in $jj3
do
    echo "$el1"
done

for el2 in $jj4
do
    echo "$el2"
done

for i in $( david ); do
    echo item: $i
done
```

Now the question I have is -

If you see my Python script, I am printing out `start` and then executing my shell script, if there are any errors in executing my shell script, then it won't print out `end`. In the above example, it won't print out `end` as there is an error.

1. Firstly, So is this the right way to do this kind of problem?
   Basically, I want to print `start` first and if the shell script got
   executed successfully, then I want to print `end`. But if for
   whatever reason, my shell script doesn't got executed successfully,
   then I won't print out `end`.
2. Secondly, with this approach, I cannot see my echo statement getting printed out on the console from the shell script? Does it mean, my shell script are getting executed but it is not getting printed out on the console somehow?
3. Thirdly, Is there any possibility of extracting the error message from the shell script, meaning whatever was the reason of shell script getting failed?

Comment: 1. Because you print `"end"` in the `else` clause. 2. Because you pipe the shell script's stderr and stdout to your script, they're now in your variables `stderr` and `stdout`. If you want to see them on the console, print them from your Python script. 3. Extract any error messages from the variable `stderr`.

Comment: So that means, my shell scripts are getting executed and all the output results are getting stored in stdout and error in stderr?

Comment: Exactly. You might have to pass [`shell=True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) as a keyword argument OR call your script with `['/bin/bash', 'testing.sh']` though.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Thanks for suggestion. And why you are suggesting you use shell=True and call my script like this `['/bin/bash', 'testing.sh']`. Is there any advantage of doing this way? I can execute the shell script like the way I have in my above question.

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure that interpreting the `#!/bin/bash` shebang is a function of the shell executing a script. I actually have no idea why it works without `shell=True` or calling the interpreter binary with the script as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Yes, it seems like your code matches your intention.

**2.** Correct. Because you used `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, you will see no output on the console from your bash script. However, the output to stdout and stderr are captured on the next line in your variables `stdout` and `stderr` when you call `communicate()`.

**3.** Yes, and you already did it: Just check the contents of your `stderr` variable, it will hold all error messages that were printed by your shell script.